# How to graph $r = \cos\left(\frac{\theta} 2\right)$

Tags: polar-coordinates

Why is [$r= \cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dbj6fpvgmu) symmetric about the Y axis?

A curve is symmetric about y axis if $(r,θ)=(−r,−θ)$ or $(r,θ)=(r,π−θ)$

But none of these is true for the above curve as $\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi- \theta}2\right) = \sin (\theta/2)$

I have realised it's symmetric about X axis as $(r,\theta ) = (r,-\theta)$.

Another problem I am facing while graphing is that how do I recognize that there's an inner part in the curve (like a loop)? What's the best way to graph this curve on XY plane?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike many common examples of polar functions, the period of your function is not $2\pi$ but $4\pi$. As a result, it makes sense to consider the transformation $\theta \to 2\pi-\theta$.  Note that
$$
  \begin{align}
    &\cos\left(\frac{2\pi-\theta}{2}\right) = -\cos(\theta/2), \\
    &\cos(2\pi-\theta) = \cos(\theta),  \text{ and } \\
    &\sin(2\pi-\theta) = -\sin(\theta).
  \end{align}
$$
As a result,
$$
  \begin{align}
    \cos\left(\frac{2\pi-\theta}{2}\right)&(\cos(2\pi-\theta),\sin(2\pi-\theta)) \\ &= -\cos(\theta/2)(\cos(\theta), -\sin(\theta)) 
    = \cos(\theta/2)(-\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)).
  \end{align}
$$

Here's a [modification of your Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/flwerxyhrd) to illustrate:

[image]